# I downloaded and installed pip. How to install packages?

Tags: python, pip

I downloaded and installed pip in Ubuntu. Then I tried to install packages like PLY and My xml etc. But I got a a sequence of sentences written in red. I used `pip install ply.3.4.jar` to install. What can I do to install packages?

Comment: Why *ply.3.4. **jar***??? JAR means "Java ARchive" and has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use instead:

```
pip install ply
```

See [how to install from pip](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/#installing-from-pypi).

pip actually downloads and install the package and its dependencies, so you do not need to download the file separately.

The other option would be to [download ply](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ply/3.4) (or any other package) yourself, and install it yourself. In my system it was installed at: 
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply`

Answer (score 1):

**First to search for a package on PyPI**

```
pip search <seach_string>
```

*Example:*

```
pip search ply | grep -i '^ply'
```

*Output:*

```
plyer                     - Platform-independant wrapper for platform-dependant APIs
plyvel                    - Plyvel, a fast and feature-rich Python interface to LevelDB
plywood                   - A template language grammar inspired by the Python code aesthetic
ply                       - Python Lex & Yacc
plytix-retailers-sdk      - Plytix Retailers SDK for Python
plymgf                    - A MGF files reader with PLY
plyfile                   - PLY file reader/writer
plypatch                  - Ply: Git-based Patch Management
plyj                      - A Java parser written in Python using PLY.
plyr                      - UNKNOWN
PlyPlus                   - a friendly yet powerful LR-parser written in Python
```

---

**Then Install the package you want:**

```
pip install <package_name>
```

*Example:*

```
pip install ply
```